# @EJB makes program crash

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, ejb

Working on a basic web application with JavaEE. I've created a JavaBean, a Bean Interface, a Servlet, an Entity and a Jsp page (attached bellow). When I request the servlet URL it get error message `Error instantiating servlet class and the root cause is:`

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [com.packageName.UserServlet/userDao] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [com.packageName.UserServlet].
```

The weird thing (in my opinion) is that when I remove the @EJB annotation in the UserServlet class, it works. I don't understand why..

If I just remove the @EJB it's a problem when executing `userDao.addUser(user)` (NullPointerException) which I think is because I removed the the @EJB?

I'm a beginner to JavaEE so my terminology might be a bit wrong but I hope you understand my problem.

Class: UserServlet

```
@WebServlet(name = "UserServlet", urlPatterns = {"/UserServlet"})
public class UserServlet extends HttpServlet {

@EJB("UserDaoBean") <---- This annotation makes it crash
private UserDaoLocal userDao;

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    int userId = 2;
    User user = new User(userId, "userName", "password");
    userDao.addUser(user);
    request.getRequestDispatcher("userinfo.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

Class: User

```
@Entity
@Table
@NamedQueries(@NamedQuery(name = "User.getAll", query = "select e from User e"))
public class User implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column
private int userid;
@Column
private String name;
@Column
private String password;

public User() {
}

public User(int userid, String name, String password) {
    this.userid = userid;
    this.name = name;
    this.password = password;
}

public int getUserid() {
    return userid;
}

public void setUserid(int userid) {
    this.userid = userid;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
}
```

Class: UserDaoLocal

```
public interface UserDaoLocal {

void addUser(User user);

}
```

Class: UserDaoBean

```
@Local
@Stateless(name = "UserDaoBean")
public class UserDaoBean implements UserDaoLocal {

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;

public UserDaoBean() {
}

@Override
public void addUser(User user) {
    entityManager.persist(user);
}
}
```

Comment: What application server are you using?  Standalone Tomcat, even with the jars to get this to compile, isn't going to work.  Are you using Glassfish or Wildfly as an example?

Comment: I'm using IntelliJ as IDE where I use TomCat 7.0.70. As database I use PostgreSql. I've added "postgresql jdbc driver" to the external library. I've also added a jsp-api and a servlet-api to the Tomcat folder.

Answer (score 1):

why are you annotating the `UserDaoBean` with `@localbean` annotation when you already have a `interface view`, `@localbean` should be used if there is `no- interface view`. annotate the interface with `@local` annotation since it represents the bean's local view. and it seems that you  have given a name to the bean

```
@Stateless(name = "UserDaoBean")
public class UserDaoBean implements UserDaoLocal {}
```

since you have overidden the default class name you cant just use 
 `@EJB` specify the bean name with `@EJB(beanName="UserDaoBean")
private UserDaoLocal  userDao;`

or just remove the `name` attribute in the `stateless annotation`

```
@Stateless
public class UserDaoBean implements UserDaoLocal {}
```

And make the ejb call like this

```
    @EJB
    UserDaoLocal userbean
```

Make sure to clean and build before running it.

Comment: Updated the classes according to your suggestions. Now I get a syntax error at: @EJB("UserDaoBean"). Maybe I didn't understand your suggestion all the way?

Comment: use `@EJB(name ="UserDaoBean")`. instead of `@EJB("UserDaoBean")`.

Comment: When I change to that, I still get the: `javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [UserDaoBean] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [UserDaoBean].`

I don't get the whole package name (in front of the "UserDaoBean") though...

Answer (score 0):

`@WebServlet` seems not work very naturally with EJB injection.
In your exception, we can see that the container used a weird JNDI name to locate your EJB instance : `com.packageName.UserServlet/userDao`

Even if it is boiler plate code, you could try to do as in the past to bypass this problem : declare your EJB in your web.xml such as :

```
 <ejb-local-ref>
    <ejb-ref-name>UserDaoBean</ejb-ref-name>
    <ejb-ref-type>Session</ejb-ref-type>
    <local>yourPackage.UserDaoBean</local>
  </ejb-local-ref>
```